# MySQL/Hibernate randomly has "Communications link failure"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

We have a webapp running Hibernate/C3PO 4.1.4.Final, Jetty, Java 6, and Mysql 5.1.63.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Communications link
>   failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 238,519
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   0 milliseconds ago.

Our persistence.xml's properties section looks like this...

```
  <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <!--Begin Credentials -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                  value="${rp.config.db.url}&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${rp.config.db.user}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${rp.config.db.password}"/>
        <!--End Credentials -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.printlogix.rp.server.utils.Mysql5BitBooleanDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <!--C3PO -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                  value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="25"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="120"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="150"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="25"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement" value="0"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;"/>

    </properties>
```

Our timeout on MySQL is set to 600 seconds.  We have no idea how this is happening 1/5 times.  The server has very little load, the database is relatively small, the servlets all run within seconds.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Is there any problem in communication between computers hosting Jetty and MySQL? Some kind of firewall?

Comment: what are the transactions that you are doing to cause such a case? How long do they last? If they last more that the MySQL timeout, then try breaking the transaction to multiple batch transactions. Sources: Been there, done that (if that is the case what I described :))

Comment: First of all is your mysql operational? and is this parameter pointing to the correct url -rp.config.db.url?

Comment: Yes MySQL is operational and working.  We are able to make calls to it 95% of the time but 5% it will randomly drop off.

Answer (score 3):

This article explains the fix.  C3P0 does not reconnect when a connection is expired.

http://www.databasesandlife.com/automatic-reconnect-from-hibernate-to-mysql/

It seems  completely insane that the developers at Hibernate would not document this better.

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced the same problem on production server. By default MySQL resets the connections in every 8 hour and hence we were getting communication failure in almost every 8 hour because we were accessing the database continuously with scheduled jobs. We solved it by increasing 'wait_timeout' to 14 days and as our maintenance is scheduled in every 15 days, we restart the each of MySQL server is our DB cluster (We have Master-Master replication in place). With approach we haven't get any communication link failure after that. In fact some time we don't restart the server in every 15 days but still no error(touch wood). :)
As per your description it seems you have set wait_timeout to be 10 minutes, so I guess you would be getting the errors with time difference of about  10 minutes. Please note it is not necessary to have to this error on every MySQL connection reset after wait_timeout. It would be there only if you are accessing the database at that time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554353/database-connection-to-mysql-times-out-even-after-setting-c3p0-testconnectiononc) might help. If it is the case, increasing the value of `wait_timeout` only postpones the ocurrence more time, rather than solving the problem.

The problem could be related with this:

- You open an hibernate session
- Do some things that take more time than the value of [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html) of your database
- You try to use this hibernate session. The message that you comment here will appear

I've documented a case in [here](http://www.supermanhamuerto.com/doku.php?id=java:thelastpacketsuccessfullyreceivedfromserver) if you are interested.