# Hibernate app can't connect to MySQL after MySQL reboot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a webapp that is running on amazon ec2 on tomcat with hibernate and rest, my mySQL is standalone instance through amazon rds.

Once i start my webapp - everything is working fine, but recently i configured daily backups on my database and then started seeing problems with my webapp connecting to mySQL.

Basically the problem is only happens if my webapp was started before i mysql instance was restarted(backed up). Then after mySQL restart for some reason any connections to it from my webapp are failing.

It all resolves once i restart my ec2 vm (It might resolve if i restart tomcat as well, but i haven't tried that)

How can i make sure my webapp gets connected back to the mysql after mysql restart?

This is what im getting written to my log:

```
21-May-2015 11:42:27.857 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
21-May-2015 11:42:27.857 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 200,187 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

Any suggestions on what to dig into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a connection pool. For Hibernate, you can use c3p0.
In your hibernate properties set the following

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
```

Then, in a c3p0.properties file, put these properties to retry to reconnect indefinitely every 3 seconds when database is down:

```
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 0
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay = 3000
c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure = false
```

See [this section](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_recovery) for more details on how to recover from a database outage.

Comment: Thank you, combining your answer with this one solved my problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752667/warn-sqlexceptionhelper143-sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-sqlexceptionhelper